# Not able to update the state, getting error as `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update my strikes, but while i do, getting error as

> Cannot read property 'strikes' of undefined

What is the error with my code? any one help me to figure out?

here is my class:

Cannot read property 'strikes' of undefined

```js
    class LightningCounter extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          strikes: 0
        };
      }

      timerTick() {
        this.setState({
          strikes: this.state.strikes + 100 //getting red underline here
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);
      }

      render() {
        return <h1>{this.state.strikes}</h1>;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Bind your timerTick function in your constructor, `this.timerTick = this.timerTick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of the context of this keyword,
the this timertick doesnt know that it belongs to class, it is pointing to itself as function.

use arrow function which is a ES6 standard now like this

```
timerTick = () => {
`enter code here`
}
```

or in the constructor bind the function this way

```
this.timerTick = this.timerTick.bind(this);
```

Check the documentation of bind to get more clarity

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Hope it works